# Access S3 using Aspera

Tags: amazon-s3, ibm-cloud

I have some files in S3 storage but I need to download them with a software which do not support S3 but supports Aspera.

Is it possible to access the S3 with Aspera protocol?

thx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Aspera protocol ([FASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_and_Secure_Protocol)) is a proprietary accelerated file transfer protocol.

It required to have a server near the storage to be able to use it.
All IBM Aspera clients (desktop, web, CLI, SDK) are free of charge. But not server.

An easy way to enable FASP on S3 (or other public cloud storage), is to subscribe to the Aspera on Cloud service.
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/aspera

The documentation shows how to connect the Aspera service to your S3 bucket: https://ibmaspera.com/help/adding_aws_s3_bucket